# Multiline formula in the directory

Tags: equations, directory

I have a formula directory with long equations and I want to have a new line included in the directory, but not in the document. How do I solve this? I shortened my main.tex down to this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{FS.tex}
\newglossaryentry{For:A}{type=For, name=\ensuremath{\alpha = \alpha} , 
    description={qwhehrqwrhjklsdhoahsjkhfasjklfhaslkh.}
 }
\newglossaryentry{For:K}{type=For, name=\ensuremath{a = b + c + d + e + d + b + c + \newline
        d + e + d c + d + e + d + b + mit a = cdasdf}, 
    description={qwhehrqwrhjklsdhoahsjkhfasjklfhaslkh ("`Flow Resistance (TL)"') .}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ captions=tableheading, chapterprefix, BCOR=4mm, cdfont=false]{tudscrreprt}      

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % European  encoding
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Mathematik
\usepackage{csquotes}               % Zitierstil
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=false]{biblatex} %style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear
%\addbibresource{Quellen.bib}        % Bibtex Quelle - EDIT: Commented out as not available or given
\usepackage{wasysym}                %Symbole wie Durchmesser

%==================================== Abkürzungs-, Symbol-, Formelverzeichnis ================================================
\usepackage[nomain, xindy, nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}


\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}

%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\newglossary[taa]{Abk}{tab}{tac}{Abkürzungen}

%Formelverzeichnis 
\newglossary[tfa]{For}{tfb}{tfc}{Formeln}

%Symbolverzeichnis
\newglossary[tsa]{Symb}{tsb}{tsc}{Symbole}

% -- Glossary-Style -- %%
\newglossarystyle{symbol}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}lp{2cm}p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}}
        {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*\glossaryheader{%
        \textbf{Zeichen} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \bigskip 
        \\}%
    \renewcommand*\glsgroupheading[1]{%
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{%
            \textbf{%
                \ifstr{##1}{G}{griechische Symbole}{%
                    \ifstr{##1}{L}{lateinische Symbole}{%
                        andere Symbole (##1)}%
                }%
            }%
        }%
        \tabularnewline
    }%
    %\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%<-- veraltet
    %\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##4 & ##3  \\}%
    \renewcommand*\glossentry[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrysymbol{##1} & 
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
    }%
}


\makeglossaries                         % Generate glossaries
\loadglsentries{FS.tex}     %Lade Einträge der Abkürzungs-, Symbol-, Formelverzeichnisse




\begin{document}
    \printglossary[type=For]
    
\chapter{A}
\begin{equation}
    \gls{For:A}
\end{equation}
Text.
\begin{equation}
    \gls{For:K}
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest would be to define the glossary as a longtable environment with a fixed width first column. This does not affect the appearance of the formulas in the main text. Then the formulas do not need an explicit newline, as the tabular will break them automatically.

```
\begin{filecontents}{FS.tex}
\newglossaryentry{For:A}{type=For, name=\ensuremath{\alpha = \alpha} , 
    description={qwhehrqwrhjklsdhoahsjkhfasjklfhaslkh.}
 }
\newglossaryentry{For:K}{type=For, name=\ensuremath{a = b + c + d + e + d + b + c +
        d + e + d c + d + e + d + b + mit a = cdasdf}, 
    description={qwhehrqwrhjklsdhoahsjkhfasjklfhaslkh ("`Flow Resistance (TL)"') .}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ captions=tableheading, chapterprefix, BCOR=4mm, cdfont=false]{tudscrreprt}      

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % European  encoding
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Mathematik
\usepackage{csquotes}               % Zitierstil
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=false]{biblatex} %style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear
%\addbibresource{Quellen.bib}        % Bibtex Quelle - EDIT: Commented out as not available or given
\usepackage{wasysym}                %Symbole wie Durchmesser

%==================================== Abkürzungs-, Symbol-, Formelverzeichnis ================================================
\usepackage[nomain, xindy, nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}


\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}

%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\newglossary[taa]{Abk}{tab}{tac}{Abkürzungen}

%Formelverzeichnis 
\newglossary[tfa]{For}{tfb}{tfc}{Formeln}

%Symbolverzeichnis
\newglossary[tsa]{Symb}{tsb}{tsc}{Symbole}

\newglossarystyle{fixedwdcol}{
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
        \longtable{p{7cm}p{\glsdescwidth}}
    }{
        \endlongtable
    }
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} 

     % set how each entry should appear:
      \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}
        &
        \glossentrydesc{##1} \\
    }
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentry{##2}{##3}
    }
}


\makeglossaries                         % Generate glossaries
\loadglsentries{FS.tex}     %Lade Einträge der Abkürzungs-, Symbol-, Formelverzeichnisse

\begin{document}
    \printglossary[style=fixedwdcol,type=For]
    
\chapter{A}
\begin{equation}
    \gls{For:A}
\end{equation}
Text.
\begin{equation}
    \gls{For:K}
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I needed a few minutes to understand what I need to do. To help people implementing your code, these tips: Add the code about newglossarystyle as a second glossarystyle to your code (do not overwrite). Then you  add style=fixedwdcol to all \printglossary that should have fixed columnwidht. It's sound easy, It took me still 15 minutes to check.